# Circular references when working with delegates and forms in multiple projects

Tags: c#, delegates

My solution consist of the following projects:

- MainApp: main form that opens the rest of forms
- DeviceAcquisition1: controls acquisition of device1 and raises an event when data is read.
- DeviceAcquisition2: controls acquisition of device2 and raises an event when data is read
- Signal Monitoring: plots the data received from device1 or device2 (only one is connected and collecting data)
- Data Analysis: plots data collected

I want to subscript to the event from SignalMonitoring but I have the problem of circular references. This is what I am trying to do:

MainForm.cs

```
private void btnCollectData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Device1BoardForm = new gUSBampBoard();
    Device1BoardForm.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

DeviceAcquisition1 and DeviceAcquisition2

```
 private void btnSignalMonitoring_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       //Show new form
       var signalMonitoringForm = new SignalMonitor();
        signalMonitoringForm.Parent = this;

       // Subscribe to event
        DeviceAcq1.DataRead += signalMonitoringForm.OnDataRead;//CANNOT DO THAT!

        signalMonitoringForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

SignalMonitoring

```
        public void OnDataRead(object source, RawdataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.rawData.Length > 0)
        {
            AddData(e.rawData);
        }
    }
```

However I cannot subscribe because DeviceAcqusition1 has the SignalMonitoring as reference and I cannot add DeviceAcquisition1 inside SignalMonitoring because then I have circular references. I need to load the form and subscribe to the delegate. How can I do it?

Comment: sometimes just changing namespaces/project names can really make the problem obvious to fix. Ex: try changing your assembly names to UI.MainApp, UI.Common.DeviceAcquisition1, UI.Common.DeviceAcquisition2 etc

Answer (score 1):

As both `SignalMonitoring` and `MainApp` are both apps, neither should be referenced from the DeviceAcquisition projects. Try to lay things out so that the apps depend on the DeviceAcquisition projects but not the other way around.

For you particular case, just move the `RawdataEventArgs` to `SignalMonitoring` and you should be good to go.

<s>Add an interface inside the `SignalMonitoring` that the DeviceAcqusition projects can implement. That way the DeviceAcqusition projects can depend on `SignalMonitoring` and not the other way around.</s>

Comment: Do you mean an interface containing the method OnDataRead()? where should I put the RawdataEventArgs class?